# Connection error in Cassandra

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra

I've installed cassandra using the following command on ubuntu 16.04 :

```
sudo apt-get install cassandra
```

It is installed now and when I run the command :

```
sudo service cassandra status
```

it is showing following :

```
● cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cassandra; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Wed 2016-09-14 17:01:17 IST; 11min ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

 Sep 14 17:01:17 ishan-HP-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Starting LSB: distributed st
Sep 14 17:01:17 ishan-HP-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Started LSB: distributed sto
Sep 14 17:06:05 ishan-HP-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Started LSB: distributed sto
Sep 14 17:08:53 ishan-HP-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Started LSB: distributed sto
Sep 14 17:08:57 ishan-HP-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Started LSB: distributed sto
lines 1-10/10 (END)
```

I think it is installed correctly with version 3.0.8. But when I try to run :

```
cqlsh
```

then it is showing the following error :

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

I have no idea why it is happening and any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sudo service cassandra status` gives me "Cassandra is running" as an answer. So I am assuming, that your cassandra is properly installed, but not yet running? Did you do `sudo service cassandra start`?

Comment: yes, I did.
It didn't show anything but still the same error after running 'cqlsh' command.

Comment: What does `nodetool status` say?

Comment: It is not showing anything relevant and showing something like its usage.

Comment: Can you please copy&pase what it says?

Comment: usage: nodetool [(-u <username> | --username <username>)]
        [(-pw <password> | --password <password>)] [(-h <host> | --host <host>)]
        [(-pwf <passwordFilePath> | --password-file <passwordFilePath>)]
        [(-p <port> | --port <port>)] <command> [<args>]

The most commonly used commands are : 
(Now it is showing some commands)

Comment: `nodetool status`, not just `nodetool`.

Comment: This is the output of nodetool status @JanDoerrenhaus :

Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  234.68 KiB  256          100.0%            efd6eb14-69d6-42a3-aea6-1a4cefce3515  rack1

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked with `netstat -ant` what is the ip address listening to port 9042? If you followed the [guidelines](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html) (the quickstart should be enough) then try to connect with `cqlsh ipaddress`.

Comment: I am not able to see any ip address with port 9042. Where can I change this port no. ?

Comment: That means your configuration is wrong. Double check your `listen_address`, `seeds`, `rpc_address ` parameters. And check your log files.

Comment: listen_address : 127.0.01
seeds : "127.0.0.1"
rpc_address: <NOTHING>
start_rpc: true
I think these fields are correct.